# Best way to send data from controller to view after a form is submitted?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I'm developing a basic web app using the MVC architecture. I'm building my own to try and fully understand how the MVC arch works so this doubles as a learning exercise.

I am using the Aura Router classes to map my URLs to controllers and action so that something like mysite.com/login will be mapped to LoginController and if I submit a form to mysite.com/login/login it will map it to LoginController->doAction('login').

Example of a controller looks like this:

```
class LoginController implements iController {

    public function doAction( PDO $dbh, $action ) {

        switch( $action ) {
            case 'login':
                //login here
                $user = new User();
                $user_id = FALSE;

                if( $user_id = $user->login( $_POST['email'], $_POST['password'] ) ) {
                    //save user id to session
                }
                else {
                    $results = array( 'errors' => array( 'invalid' ) );
                    MembershipFunc::redirect( '/login', $results );
                }

                break;
            case 'logout':
                //logout
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is that to avoid people from refreshing the page and resubmitting the data I like to forward the user back to the login page if the login failed. Currently if I don't forward them then they would appear on the page mysite.com/login/login and I don't think it's particularly clean. It's okay for my simple login form because an error could redirect to mysite.com/login?error=email,password&email=user@domain.com but in the case of a huge form then I would get a huge URL query which is really gross.

I have scoured for good resources with basic (yet useful) PHP code examples on how MVC works and I've struggled to find anything particularly useful. Should I avoid mapping my URL structures to an action and instead opt for putting a POST field called "action" instead? Should I somehow build a system where I pass this data through an array in the SESSION data?

Any advice?

*Note: I would just like to specify that I know this question doesn't fit in the SO culture because it might not have a right/wrong answer but I find SO always has the best/most knowledgeable user-base. If anyone has tips as to where I should direct these questions I would really appreciate it so I don't add clutter!*

Comment: Why is your controller aware of DB connection? Why does it have only one method? Is `iController` copyrighted by Apple?

Comment: If you have a *switch* in your method, you need several methods.

Comment: I'll contact my patent agent to make sure :-P. Oops I can't add new lines in these comments. I'm just passing the DB connection down so I don't have to create a new one when going to the models. I create the DB in my index.php/bootloader file and then pass it to the controller which keeps trickling it down.

Comment: I appreciate that people upvote/downvote questions but for the downvoters I would appreciate if you'd at least let me know where I could get advice on these types of questions. I work alone so I'm not surrounded by peers in my field hence why I turn to SO.

Comment: Please, look up "clean code talks" on youtube, and then read stuff from M.Folwer on the subject of MVC and design patterns in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my MVC URLs look like:
index.php?c=Controller&m=ControllerMethod&d=slash/sepparated/list/of/stuff

Data (d=) is exploded on the slashes and passed as an array to every controller method.
Autoloading (via spl_autoload_register()) is used to call the class (c=) and then the method in that class (m=).

Also, it sounds like you're either not setting the ACTION on your form or you're deliberately setting the ACTION to GET. As a general rule, ACTION should be POST to keep the URLs sane. Except search forms. Those can be GET with various advantages.

Re-directing to prevent a resubmitted form on refresh is your best option (probably only option). But in my MVC index.php?c=user&m=login handles both the login page and the login action.

**Example**

```
class login extends Controller {

    public function login($data) {

        if(empty($_POST)) {

            $this->view = "login.tpl";

            return TRUE;

        }


        $res = $this->model->auth();

        if($res !== TRUE) {

            $_POST = NULL;

            $this->errorState = 1;
            $this->errorMsg = "Invalid login details";

            $this->login();

            return FALSE;

        }

        Core::setMessage('success', 'user', 'login', '2', 'Logged in successfully');

        $home = new home(); //whatever the main controller is
        $home->index($data);

        //alternatively you can redirect

        header("Location: index.php?c=home&m=index);

        return TRUE;

    }

}
```

Does this make sense or have I completely missed the mark?

Comment: So you would advise to set the actions through a hidden field in my forms. Now how does your Core::setMessage() function send the information to your view if you redirect the user and lose the post data?

Comment: My MVC skeleton isn't designed to handle that situation. If I had or wanted to I'd store the global $PAGE variable in $_SESSION or $_COOKIE or something (likely $_SESSION) and use it when the page landed. In my setup we use Smarty for the template engine and Pines Notify for messages/errors. We only assign two variables to smarty, $PAGE as PAGE and $this->view as TPL which loads the inner template and all those messages set by Core:setMessage(); as well as the one from $this->errorState and $this->errorMessage are stored in $PAGE['messages'].

Comment: We also don't set a message for a successful login. It's pretty obvious it was a success when you see the landing page.

Comment: I can't 'comment everywhere' so I'll put this here: Use a Global DB handler. ie global $db; and then you can use it everywhere by redeclaring global $db anywhere you want it to have scope and use it.