# Chaning the content of a site when extension changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok so i am creating a website for a friend and he wants the site to work in the following way.

He has one page that has two sections that can appear. Only one section can appear at one time. A button is used to switch between the different sections. The way im currently doing this is by using two div's and dispalying/hiding them when the button is pressed. So if section 1 is showing and the button is pressed section 1 will fade out and section two will face in.

This all works great, however what he would like it to be able to send people links to his site and depending on the extension show that particular section. For example, lets say these two sections are credits and content. If he send someone the url of www.site.com/credits then he would like the credits section to show. And if he sends the url of www.site.com/content then he would like the content section to show up. He would also like to maintain the button click to switch between the two.

I have been looking into it and it seems that this could be done using hash values (#) for example www.site.com#credits. Is there any way of doing this but using /'s instead of #'s?

**Edit**

The other thing about this is that he would not like the page to refresh when the button is clicked he would just like to use javascript to change the section.

Comment: Do you really want to do this using / in the url? Is this a one page website? Do you want to learn how to use mod_rewrite?

Comment: Why not use URL Parameters, like `www.site.com?dis=credits`. Then on your backend, have the controller simply check for `GET`, and based on the result display the page with a data variable. Then use that variable in your JS to determine which panel to display on `document.ready`. See [here for an example question on displaying data from url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883280/best-way-to-send-data-from-controller-to-view-after-a-form-is-submitted)

Comment: hash values will simply direct the page to that particular element

Comment: @SpYk3HH It might be a static site and there might be no `GET`.

Comment: @Ejay lol, let's hope not. Those still exist? :P

Comment: @SpYk3HH Hash values are not only used for directing a page. Check out: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/cycle-permalink-to-slide-with-custom-hash-value

Comment: @SpYk3HH Also He does not want to use URL parameters as they look messy. Like i stated in my question he wants to use /'s

Comment: @MarcAudet Yes it is a one page website. He would like to just have his One page but for the text to change within that page. It looks like im going to have to use URL parameters and like you say learn how to use mod_rewrite.

Comment: You dont have to use url params. Check out [Codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter). They have a nice setup that allows you to do things like `www.site.com/controller/method/param1/param2/param3/etc...` [See here!](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#passinguri)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running Apache, you could use the rewrite module.

For example, setting it up like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(credits|content)/?$ switch.php?view=$1
```

Then in *switch.php* you have to evaluate the `view` variable you `GET` with the URL which section would be show by default.

Answer (score 0):

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426958/get-page-url-using-javascript) will help you get last portion from your url, based on that you can hide/display your content or credits.

```
jQuery(function() {
var url, page, n;
url = window.location.pathname;
n = url.lastIndexOf('/');
if (n >= 0) {
    page = url.substring(n + 1);
}
if(page == "content"){
//display content
} else {
//display credits
}
});
```